# Подгружается на тот шаблон Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.0

После очистки кэша модификаторов, происходит что-то странное. Пытаюсь подгрузить шаблон product.tpl в папку system/storage/modification/catalog/veiw/theme/default/template/product/ - изменения происходят, но когда я подгружаю category.tpl в ту же папку - изменения не происходят. Что за магия?
Opencart 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Конфликт был в модификаторах. Выключил Layered Navigation Ajax и всё стало на свои места.